# Need help in making a stored procedure to be called for every record

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been having a hard time converting my nested select statement to a stored procedure. What I have now is that I can get the value I need PER record but I don't know how to make it to make the query run for ALL records instead of just one. Here is what I have

```
SELECT
TICKETNUMBER, [TABLE].[END DATE]

FROM

(   
SELECT TOP 1
    BR.TicketNumber,
    RM.SMDC_EXECUTIONNO,
    RM.SMDC_DATEAPPROVED as [END DATE]  
FROM
    INCIDENT BR JOIN BUYERREQUEST RM ON BR.INCIDENTID = RM.BUYERREQUESTID
WHERE
    RM.STATUSCODE = 5 OR RM.STATUSCODE = 6 OR RM.STATUSCODE = 100000000 AND BR.TICKETNUMBER = '2014-001155'
ORDER BY RM.executionno DESC

) AS [TABLE]
```

As you can see, I can get the needed ticket number and end date for one record (Ticket number 2014-001155, a sample record) But I need to do this for all 8000 records I have. I hope someone there could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you supplied is not a stored procedure, and if your goal is to run it for everyrecord you should probably be looking into Functions instead.

But you can run that query for every ticket number on a SourceTable with OUTER APPLY

```
select
    Source.TicketNumber,
    TICKETNUMBER, 
    [TABLE].[END DATE]
from mySourceTable Source
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
    TICKETNUMBER, [TABLE].[END DATE]

    FROM

    (   
    SELECT TOP 1
        BR.TicketNumber,
        RM.SMDC_EXECUTIONNO,
        RM.SMDC_DATEAPPROVED as [END DATE]  
    FROM
        INCIDENT BR JOIN BUYERREQUEST RM ON BR.INCIDENTID = RM.BUYERREQUESTID
    WHERE
        RM.STATUSCODE = 5 OR RM.STATUSCODE = 6 OR RM.STATUSCODE = 100000000 AND BR.TICKETNUMBER = Source.TicketNumber
    ORDER BY RM.executionno DESC

    ) AS [TABLE]
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out what you would have the stored procedure do or how you would call it from a query. I also can't figure out why you need a nested query if all you want is the latest date for each ticket. It looks like you should get what you want for every ticket number with the a much simpler query:

```
SELECT  BR.TicketNumber, Max( RM.SMDC_DATEAPPROVED ) as [END DATE]  
FROM    INCIDENT     BR
JOIN    BUYERREQUEST RM
    ON  BR.INCIDENTID = RM.BUYERREQUESTID
WHERE   RM.STATUSCODE in( 5, 6, 100000000 )
GROUP BY BR.TicketNumber
ORDER BY BR.TicketNumber;
```